# How do I get my Rails controller to return an array instead of a string in my JSON response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model-view-controller

I'm using Rails 5.1.  I have a controller that returns this data ...

```
class CurrenciesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: { data: currency_list.to_json }
  end
```

When I call the API from a command line, using wget, the response looks like this

```
{"data":"[{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"EUR\",\"rate\":1,\"country\":\"Europe\",\"created_at\":\"2019-08-15T13:42:23.606Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-08-15T13:42:23.606Z\"},{\"id\":...
```

When Javascript parses this JSON, the "data" element is interpreted as a string, which I guess makes sense since the value is enclosed in quotes.  My question is, how do I change the value from a string to an array?  I would like the data to be returned as

```
{"data":[{"id":2,"name":"EUR","rate":1,"country":"Europe","created_at":"2019-08-15T13:42:23.606Z","updated_at":"2019-08-15T13:42:23.606Z"},{"id":...
```

Not sure what else I need to do in my controller to achieve this.

Comment: remove `.to_json` from `currency_list`.

Comment: Yup that was it!